# Ask user if they want results printed in upper or lower case python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code below... but can't seem to get it to work. For starters, if the user types that they want the results printed in uppercase, it stays lower case. In addition to this, the results instead of displaying in one organized list, the code just keeps looping individually through the contents. What am I doing wrong?

```
def list_movies(movies):
   

        for i in range(0, len(movies)):
            movie = movies[i]
            case = input("Would you like it printed in (U)pper or (L)ower case? ").strip().lower()
            if case == "u":
                print(str(i+1) + ". " + movie[0] + " (" + movie[1] + ")".upper())
            else:
        
                print(str(i+1) + ". " + movie[0] + " (" + movie[1] + ")")
            print()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain, in your own words, what you expect `")".upper()` to do, exactly? You're applying `.upper()` only to this close parenthesis string; encapsulate your concatenated string in parenthesis and call `.upper()` on that to get the effect you (seem to) desire.

Comment: "*In addition to this...*" Please edit your question to focus on a single, answerable query that adheres to our [ask] standards and is on topic per the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic]. If you have additional inquiries, you should post a separate question; otherwise, your post is a bit too broad for the Q&A format here.

Comment: The code in this post could be made significantly smaller and still demonstrate the issue - in other words I recommend that you make a [mre] to help yourself and others understand the issue better without having to think about all that other code that has nothing to do with the issue. Also, the fix for this is that instead of building your string within the `print()`, you can do it outside of `print()` and assign it to a variable, then you can just do `print(var.upper())` or `print(var.lower())`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a great start, but I think some of your issues can be solved by refactoring to make it less complicated.

For example, I think if you used an additional variable it would have been more clear to see your issue. This line:
`print(str(i+1) + ". " + movie[0] + " (" + movie[1] + ")".upper())` is not doing what you think it is. The `upper()` method is only being applied to the `")"`. To avoid this in the future, I suggest using an [f string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/ and a local variable to store the output string. This would make it easier to read, and thus less error-prone. In addition, I'd suggest that you restructure your list movies logic to slightly decouple it from the if statements. This will further make it easier to read. For example, try this:

```
def list_movies(movies):
    #ask the user if they want it printed in upper or lower case using .upper()/.lower()

      for movie in movies:
          output_string = f"{str(i+1)}.{movie[0] ( {movie[1]} \n)}"

          case = input("Would you like it printed in (U)pper or (L)ower case? ").strip().lower()
          if case == "u":
              output_string = output_string.upper()
        
          print(output_string)
```

Now it is more clear where the upper case is being applied, and you don't need an else statement.